# jQuery AJAX URL Ampersand (&) Formatting

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using the following script I am capturing date value from jQuery datepicker and passing that on to a jQuery AJAX call.  Everything is working, but running into an issue with ampersands in the AJAX URL.

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#datepicker').datepicker({
           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
              onSelect: function (date) {

                //capture date values from datepicker  
                var date = date;
                var year = date.substr(0,4);
                var month = date.substr(5,2);
                var day = date.substr(8,2);
                var url = "http://www.example.com?view=week" + "&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&date=" + day;


                //ajax events load
                $.ajax({url: url ,success:function(result){
                  $("#ajaxEvents").html(result);
                }});

                //close datepicker
                $('#datepicker').toggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('close');

                return false;
          }

      })

    });
  </script>
```

When I inspect the AJAX request using fiddler you can see the URL format is as follows:

```
http://www.example.com?view=week&amp;year=2014&amp;month=01&amp;date=23
```

Note that all the '&' characters were converted in the URL. In order for the query to work correctly I need the format to be:

```
http://www.example.com?view=week&year=2014&month=01&date=23
```

Any ideas how I can prevent the format from changing in the AJAX request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data element to your jQuery ajax function

```
  data: { year: "2014", month: "Jan", date: "15" }
```

jquery will add it to the URL for you.

```
 //ajax events load
 $.ajax({url: url, data: { year: '"'+year+'"', month: '"'+month+'"', date: '"'+day+'"'} ,success:function(result){
 $("#ajaxEvents").html(result);
 }});
```

Comment: I had to change the format a little, but this gives the request i need. Thanks! 

$.ajax({url: url2, data: { year: + year, month: + month , date: + day} ,success:function(result){
     $("#ajaxEvents").html(result);
}});

Comment: Using the URL request gets sent as http://www.example.com?year=2014&month=1&date=29

Comment: Sorry I double "ed the vars, they need to be strings and in your case they are already strings. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Information is not supposed to be sent manually in the url when using the ajax function. Try using it like this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com";
var data = "view=week" + "&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&date=" + day;

$.ajax({
       url: url ,
       success: function(result){$("#ajaxEvents").html(result);},
       data: data
});
```

What we are doing is making the query string seperately and sending into the ajax function using the data attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried your updates, but the URL request still gets sent as "http://www.example.com?view=week&amp;year=2014&amp;month=01&amp;date=23" so the query does not execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following did not work:

```
url: 'myAnalysis.php?fName='+fNameVal+'&lName='+lNameVal
```

So, I replaced it with:

```
url: 'myAnalysis.php', data: { fName: fNameVal, lName: lNameVal}
```

and it started working.